# Converting datetime to date within html template

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I have a DateTime field in my **models/db** in the form `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`. On my HTML template, I want it to be just the date in the form `'25 Dec 2000'`.

However, if I change from `{{ model.datetime }}` to `{{ model.datetime|date:'d F Y' }}`, the field on the html template then goes blank.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: So you want a date from the datetime?

Comment: what are you doing with model.datetime?

Comment: You should show your view and model code. If you're calling `strftime` on it, then it's already a string, so it's not clear what you are doing.

Comment: I want just the date in the form '25 Dec 2000', from the field which is currently in the form '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'. 
Yet when i try this, the field goes blank on the html template

Comment: Just now you repeated the same thing you have written in the description.

Comment: As requested, please add your model and view, or else it's nearly impossible to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use template filter like,

```
{{ you_date_field|date:'d M Y' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`dparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
dt_1 = "2000-12-25 17:30:00"
tempVal = (dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).date()).strftime('%d %B %Y')

print("Date: {}".format(tempVal))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Date: 25 December 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing **strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')** then you are already getting a string format of your datetime object.
And when you are doing **{{ model.datetime|date:'d F Y' }}**, here you are doing one more operation on just **string** object, thats why its returning empty.

```
date = datetime.now()
==> datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 11, 40, 17, 869441)

date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
==> '2019-04-05 11:40:25.941187' 
// This is just a string at this point you cannot further do date operations on it
```

To do date operations like **{{ model.datetime|date:'d F Y' }}**, you should do the operation on **Datetime** object only.